# What affects converging speed when training a CNN model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, convergence

I have a CNN model with user-defined loss function.

The model can not be optimized by SGD, but with AdaDelta, it converges to its theoretical value in less than 100 loops on MNIST, CIFAR, and SVHN datasets. 
In some papers, it says it always takes several hundreds and thousands loop before convergence when training a model.

Is it because the model is too complex (5 conv/pool layers) and the dataset too easy to fit?

Answer (score 1):

**There is a huge amount of things affecting the speed of convergence of the model.**

Among others:

- The architecture of the network

  - The number of layers
  - The number of parameters in each layer
  - Activation functions used
  - Other architectural details
- The dataset and the complexity of the problem
- Learning algorithm
- Hyperparameters, such as

  - Learning rate
  - Dropout rate
  - Weight decay
- Loss function
- Weight initialization

  - Random
  - Pre-trained model
- ...

Some models simply need more time, some converge faster. This cannot be simply answered. Generally, if a model is "too complex" depends on the specific task. MNIST is an easy task which can be easily learned by a small MLP. Having a good performance on MNIST within ~100 iterations should not surprise you. On the other hand, learning e.g. semantic segmentation on MS COCO dataset is a wholly different story where thousands of epochs may be required.

Comment: can you explain why the number of layers increases convergence time? All weights should be updated after each batch, so the learning effect should be similar, shouldn't it?

Comment: @fogx changing the number of layers generally changes the properties of the optimization space in which the learning algorithm operates. More layers can perhaps even lead to faster convergence.